# How Do I Run Multiple instances .java Files (running one of them as an Object or Method)

Tags: java

I am using NetBeans IDE with Java 1.8.0

What am I doing wrong here? I want to use Output.java as - I believe - a method. Is this possible or not?

As mentioned earlier, I am using Netbeans GUI editor, so it is automatically added with the Main attribute.

(Please keep in mind that I have only really started using Java for about a week now, so I only get the concept of methods and objects.)

*Edit

```
public class Main {
    Output.Main. = new JTextField();
}
```

and

```
public JTextField getIn() {
    return In;
}
```

Where

```
JTextField a = getIn();
String out = Out.setText();
```

In and Out are JTextFields

Comment: Add the Code which you have tried.

Comment: @CollinD I do not mean to offend anybody. It is nothing but a pride for my heritage and the belief in fighting for what you believe to be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, to actually run a program, a class needs to have a method "public static void main(String[] args)" defined. When you attempt to run a Java object by compiling "javac MyClass.java" and then "java MyClass", it is the main method which actually begins running.

Comment: What is the purpose of a Class then?

Comment: @Confederate3320 I'd recommend reading head first Java, and Head first design patterns. The purpose of a class is to provide a definition for what will become an instance of an object. The purpose of `main` is to tell "the system" where to start the program. You can and will have many classes, but only 1 main will ever execute, and it is usually not a good idea to have more than one class in an application with a main method.

Comment: @xenoterracide Which one do I leave as Main, the GUI or the Background code.

Comment: @Confederate3320 you do not need a `Main` class, only a `main` method. I would name classes according to their responsibility. every class should have a "single responsibility". If your options are Main, Gui, and Background, you probably have too few classes, but that's fine when you're learning and toy projects.